# MySQL order on column from left join

Tags: mysql, left-join, bigdata

Maybe someone here can help me / give a hint about how to do some stuff. We're using 2 tables in mySql, both MyISAM, utf8. The first table hold all registrations for objects, the seconds table holds all the objects with additional information like name etc.

The match between table 1 and table2 will be based on the code-column from both tables. Why not id? Because table1 is being filled with by an external system, so it doesn't know the id of the object it's linked to. Also, we can have registrations for objects which are not available in table 2, but needs to be registered in table 1.

Table1 - Registrations: (+/- 33.000.000 rows)

```
+-------------+
| id          |
| code        |
| datetime    |
+-------------+
```

Table2 - Objects: (+/- 55.000 rows)

```
+-------------+
| id          |
| code        |
| name        |
| description |
| etc.        |
+-------------+
```

Both tables has indexes on some columns. Regular select query goes fine. It creates an result of 32.382.742 rows in 0.0017 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.code = table1.code
```

When I order on columns from table 1, still ok. It creates an result of 32.382.742 rows in 0.0179 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.code = table1.code ORDER BY table1.datetime
```

When I order on columns fom table 2, it's very bad. MySQL's `SHOW processlist;` shows a temporary table being created and didn't stop for 300 seconds, so we killed MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.code = table1.code ORDER BY table2.name
```

Also tried to select from table2 with a RIGHT JOIN on table 1, but this also won't work.

How to solve this / get this fast?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `LEFT JOIN`, so the DBMS orders the rows where the columns of Table2 are `NULL` by its defaults.
Not sure if this got something to do with your problem, but you could try extending your `ORDER BY` clause like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.code = table1.code 
ORDER BY table2.name, table1.datetime
```

or (not sure if this will work)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.code = table1.code 
ORDER BY ISNULL(table2.name,table1.datetime)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Below Query:

```
Select * from
(SELECT * FROM user_product  ORDER BY user_product.user_product_id DESC) as tempPost
LEFT JOIN product_like on (product_like.user_product_id = tempPost.user_product_id)
```